gnome-terminal - Set default profile for each theme variant
I have created two custom gnome-terminal profiles, with custom colors, for light mode and dark mode (I like PaperColor). And in the gnome-terminal preferences, I have "Theme variant" set to "Follow system style". But even when gnome-terminal changes between dark theme and light theme based on system style, I have to manually swap between my two custom profiles. I could just use one profile with "Use colors from system theme" checked, but then I have ugly system theme colors instead of my preferred colors.
Is there any way to set gnome-terminal to use different custom profiles for dark theme and light theme?
Or:
Is there a way to configure the system colors to match my custom gnome-terminal profile colors? With both dark theme and light theme?

Unfortunately—as grawity also pointed out—it's not yet possible in GNOME Terminal.
The closest workaround you can do, if you'd prefer to keep using GNOME Terminal and would like to switch the look of all your terminals at once, is this:
Create a single profile that you'll be using for all your terminal windows and tabs. Create two shell scripts that change the properties of that profile. Then execute whichever of these two scripts that you wish to change to.
Such a script could go something like this (hardcode the profile ID if you want to go with a non-default profile, also obviously modify the colors according to your taste):
#!/bin/sh

default=$(dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/default | tr -d "'")

dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$default/background-color '"#abcdef"'
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$default/foreground-color '"#123456"'
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$default/palette '[
  "#000000",
  "#111111",
  "#222222",
  "#333333",
  "#444444",
  "#555555",
  "#666666",
  "#777777",
  "#888888",
  "#999999",
  "#AAAAAA",
  "#BBBBBB",
  "#CCCCCC",
  "#DDDDDD",
  "#EEEEEE",
  "#FFFFFF"]'

Note that the rgb(...,...,...) syntax, as reported by the corresponding dconf read ... commands, is equally fine.

No, gnome-terminal does not support that in its current versions.
The GNOME Prompt terminal aka Ptyxis (which is built using the same libvte terminal emulation) supports color schemes which have light and dark variants. It has no UI for selecting different schemes for each mode, but it's possible to download the scheme files from its Git repo and manually combine them into a custom scheme (install it by dragging the file onto the settings window).
Prompt/Ptyxis uses libvte with GTK4, which still has a few quirks (such as wacky mouse wheel scroll speed) compared to the libvte GTK3 variant that GNOME Terminal uses, but besides that it works well.
